# Stirling's approximation and gaps between primes

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

Let $G(n)$ denote the largest prime gap $p_{k+1}-p_k$ occuring between $1$ and $n$.

By considering the $n-1$ composite consecutive integers $n!+2$,...,$n!+n$ we can conclude that $$G(n!+n) \geq n-1 $$

Then, as mentioned on this [post](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2014/08/21/large-gaps-between-consecutive-prime-numbers/), it follows (without any proof) that by using Striling's approximation we get $$G(n) \gg \frac{\log(n)}{\log(\log(n))}$$

I tried at least to pass from $G(n!+n)$ to $G(n!)$ by considering the sequence $(n-1)!+2$,...,$(n-1)!+n-1$ and noting that the last term is smaller than $n!$ thus obtaining $$G(n!) \geq n-2$$

Now I am stumped as to how I should use Stirling's approximation. I believe I need to use the inequality $ log(n!) \leq nlog(n)$ as I read on another website (but also without any further explanation).

I would like to have a $G(n)$ instead of $G(n!)$ but I also don't know how.

How should I proceed from here?

Comment: Well, $n!+2, n!+3,\dots, n!+n$ is not quite a prime gap of size between $1$ and $m=n!+n,$ since we don't have the next prime. Bur you can define $G(m)$ to be the length of the largest sequence of consecutive non-primes from $1$ to $m.$

Comment: Why start with $(n-1)!+2$ when you can go reverse: $n!-2,n!-3,\dots, n!-n?$ For $n>3$ at least, these are all non-prime.

Comment: In any, you can choose a smaller $m=n\#,$ the [primorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/), the product of all primes $\leq n.$ Then $n\#-n,\dots, n\#-2$ gives $G(n\#)\geq n-1.$ $n\#=e^{n(1+o(1))}.$ You'll need $n>3,$ again.

Comment: This means for any $\epsilon>0$ all but finitely many cases have $G(e^{(1+\epsilon)n})\geq n-1.$

Comment: In partcular, since $n\#<3^n,$ according to the wikipedia page, $G(3^n)\geq n-1.$

Comment: By the way, $\gg$ is usually used for "much greater than."  Is that what you really meant?